# The type variable used as exception parameter

Tags: java, exception

Could you get an example for the following rule

[**JLS 14.20**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20)

> It is a compile-time error if a type variable is used in the
>   denotation of the type of an exception parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means something like this:

```
catch (MySpecialException<T> ex) {
    ...
}
```

`T` is a type variable here.

Comment: Do you mean declararation of type `T` is visible in that catch clause?

Comment: I ask that because I get a compile-time error even when I'm trying to declare a generic class extended `Throwable`. Is the restrction make a sense at all?

Comment: @St.Antario: Providing a type argument in a catch clause declaration is illegal _because_ Throwable subclasses cannot have type parameters.  There will never be a `MyException<Integer>` to catch because `MyException` cannot have type parameters, and rather than have a catch clause that never catches anything (likely a bug), it's a compile-time error.